# sitemap запрещён к индексированию тегом NOINDEX

Tags: wordpress, seo

Имеется сайт на **Wordpress** с установленным плагином **YOAST SEO**.
Выполнены все настройки, включены индексируемые разделы.

[image: Скриншот страницы /sitemap_index.xml]

*Проблема:*
В вебмастере Яндекс, в разделе "Проверка ответа сервера" пишет - "url запрещён к индексирования тегом noindex."

Как убрать данную ошибку?

**Robots.txt имеет следующий вид**

```
Host: sitename.ru
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /?
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /author/
Disallow: */embed
Disallow: */page/
Disallow: /wp-
Allow: */uploads
Allow: /*/*.js
Allow: /*/*.css
Allow: /wp-*.png
Allow: /wp-*.jpg
Allow: /wp-*.jpeg
Allow: /wp-*.gif
Allow: /wp-*.svg
Allow: /wp-*.pdf
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /privacy-policy
Sitemap: https://sitename.ru/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: https://sitename.ru/post-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://sitename.ru/page-sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://sitename.ru/wpm-testimonial-sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Пришлите ваш robots.txt

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Видимо где-то на сайте в футере или на какой-то странице стоит ссылка на сайтмап и no-follow

Comment: Ссылка есть только в файле footer.php, но атрибутов типа noindex, nofollow - там нет.